# Reference Request: Concentration inequalities/concentration of measure phenomenon

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, concentration-of-measure

Is there a good source for concentration inequalities? I've seen the standard ones (Bernstein, Hoeffding, Chernoff, etc.), but I'm hoping to get two things:

1. A ton of exercises. (Still haven't really gotten a great grasp on these inequalities, intuitively, so that's why the exercises help. They build intuition.)
2. Learn some more exotic/specific concentration inequalities (for example, for Gaussian chaos, matrix random variables, etc.)

I know of the book, "Concentration Inequalities: A Nonasymptotic Theory of Independence." Is that still the best reference out there?

Comment: Coincidentally I have also been studying concentration of measure the last few days. FWIW you can look at the book "Concentration inequalities: A nonasymptotic theory of independence", by Stephane Boucheron et al. published in 2012. This book has a preface by Ledoux himself. 

If you don't mind me asking, what problem areas do you want to use these inequalities for?

Comment: @Pushpendre, just general interest.

Comment: In that case you may start by looking at some lecture videos from Lugosi who is the second author on the above book.  Personally, I find lecture videos to be a faster way to learn the material.

Comment: @Pushpendre which lectures?

Comment: Check out Lugosi's lectures 35-38, 41-42 at https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL420ECE3D4B62F082

Comment: Alright. Looks geared towards machine learning, but I'd be generally interested in other text references.

Answer (score 2):

1) "Concentration Inequalities: A Nonasymptotic Theory of Independence" is still a standard reference. The alternatives for a general introduction also include

> Ledoux's The concentration of measure phenomenon

Broader introductions are also available in van Handel's notes on high-dimensional probability and Vershynin's High Dimensional Probability, although  they have somewhat broader scope. (These two can be easily found online).

2) For concentration for matrices,

> Joel Tropp - An Introduction to Matrix Concentration Inequalities

is the standard reference and easily found on arxiv.